# What's the origin of "shot away"?

Tags: etymology, adjectives, phrase-origin

What's the origin of the phrase "shot away" as meaning a person is behaving in an unhinged manner?

Comment: Do you have evidence that it is used that way? I think of it as meaning "left very quickly"

Comment: I cannot find _any_ general reference to support this, except Urban Dict. The rest is just Rolling Stones.

Comment: @Unrelated conversations around Southern England for years, but nothing in print.

Comment: If you stuck a bottle rocket in a bottle, pointed the bottle at an angle away from you, and then lit the rocket, you might say it "shot away".  Nothing mysterious.  Now consider when a person behaves emotionally like that rocket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Green's Dictionary of Slang*](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/pp6ep7a) offers this entry under the headword **shot**.

3. (orig. *Aus.*, also **all shot**, **shot at**, ***shot away,*** **shot through**) of a person, exhausted or in bad shape.

A variant of this is first attested in a quote by F. Scott Fitzgerald in **1920**:

> F.S. Fitzgerald ‘May Day’ in *Bodley Head Scott Fitzgerald* V (1963) 144: You certainly look **all shot**.

Not until **2000** does *GDoS* offer an attestation using the form "shot away," in the context of drugs:

> 2000   [UK]    *Indep. on Sun. Rev.* 21 May 6: He was so **shot away on pills and alcohol** that he drove his car off the road.

It's tempting to attribute all variations of this to the verb **shoot up** meaning to intravenously inject a drug, but it's worth noting that variations referring to alcohol intoxication appear to be the oldest, such as this **1838** attestation of "half shot," meaning "slightly tipsy, or partially drunk."

> **1838**   [US]    J.C. Neal *Charcoal Sketches* (1865) 13: If your tongue wasn’t so thick, I’d say you must mosey: but moseying is only to be done when a gemman’s **half shot**.

It is worth noting that there are many citations of **shot** meaning drunk that predate the phrase **shoot up** meaning to inject a drug, which is first cited in **1905** by *GDoS*:

> **1905**   [US]    F. Hutchison *Philosophy of Johnny the Gent* 70: ‘[I]f a doctor hadn’t [...] s**hot him full o’ dope** he’d ’a had the snakes on the square’.

It's possible the earlier references to being **shot** meaning drunk are figurative extensions of something that has been "shot by a gun."

For what it's worth, the *OED* indicates that a "shot" has been used to refer to a small portion of something since the 17th century -- this is likely the origin of the word **shot** in **shotgun** and **shot-glass**, as opposed to the inverse, which might seem more intuitive.

Comment: Hello R...There seems to be a problem with your link: nowhere do I find the citation at Green's "(orig. Aus., also all shot, shot at, shot away, shot through) of a person, exhausted or in bad shape." I have done several [CTRL] F's.

Comment: @Cascabel You're right, thank you.  I had linked to the noun entry instead of the adjective entry.

Answer (score 1):

McGraw-Hill's Dictionary of American Slang says that is is a variant of  ***shot up:*** <sub>[(link)](https://studfiles.net/preview/393887/page:39/)</sub>

> - ***and shot-away*** mod. alcohol or drug intoxicated. *Well, you see, he’s shot-up and can’t come to the phone.*

It appears to derive from [shot-up](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/shoot--up) with the meaning:

> - (noun Slang) an act or instance of injecting an addictive drug intravenously.
>
> First recorded in 1965–70; noun use of verb phrase shoot up.

Answer (score 1):

**shot** etymology  [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/shot)

> Figurative sense "ruined, worn out" is from 1833.

a possible reference to a person's demeanor.